# Is it possible for a foreign key referencing two different columns for different tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key

I have projects table for example:

```
Id | name | description | created_at | updated_at
```

and tasks table like

```
Id | project_id | description | created_at | updated_at
```

I have an comments table

```
Id | type_id | type | comment | user_id | created_at
```

Can `type_id` here reference both projects and tasks table ?

I want to use `type_id` as foreign key reference id in both projects and tasks table. Also type column will hold the value project and task to distinguish between if we want to get the comments of projects or tasks. I really don't know which is the perfect way to do. Should I add 2 different comments table like `project_comments` and `task_comments` and reference their primary key ?

Comment: I want to use type_id as foreign key for projects and tasks table ? Is this possible and right way of doing is my question

Comment: It seems to be possible https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9b7581aad8f7f76a4bd2ae255b983948 but type_id values must exists in both tables, and I don't believe that is what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: yes I am trying to achieve what you have showed on dbfiddle.

Comment: So is it good to have single comments table referencing projects and tasks ?

Comment: Please could you tell us which column of each table should be referenced?

Comment: I want to reference Id column sir

Comment: That's what I mean. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=160ecc8ea30ee409e66194387493ba19

Comment: Do not push FKs beyond their meager capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question:

> Is it possible for a foreign key referencing two different columns for different tables in mysql

is: YES, you can.

This [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=160ecc8ea30ee409e66194387493ba19) shows that is possible to reference two tables.

But it has no sense to me, because project.ID=1 and task.ID=1 maybe/surely are not related, and this design doesn't allow to insert any Id in one table that doesn't exists in the other.

IMHO let me suggest to use two tables, `project_comments` and `task_comments` if you want to use foreign keys, or use a single table without foreign keys. You can use a trigger or a function to ensure referential integrity.